# Creating new rows and new columns based on row data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has rows for each user joining my site and making a purchase.

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
|   | uid |        msg         |  _time  | gender | age |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
| 0 |   1 | confirmed_settings | 1/29/15 | M      |  37 |
| 1 |   1 | sale               | 4/13/15 | M      |  37 |
| 2 |   3 | confirmed_settings | 4/19/15 | M      |  35 |
| 3 |   4 | confirmed_settings | 2/21/15 | M      |  21 |
| 4 |   5 | confirmed_settings | 3/28/15 | M      |  18 |
| 5 |   4 | sale               | 3/15/15 | M      |  21 |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+--------+-----+
```

I would like to change the dataframe so that each row is unique for a uid and there is a columns called `sale` and `confirmed_settings` which have the timestamp of the action. Note that not every user has a `sale`, but every user has a `confirmed_settings`.  Like below:

```
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
|   | uid | confirmed_settings |  sale   |  _time  | gender | age |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
| 0 |   1 | 1/29/15            | 4/13/15 | 1/29/15 | M      |  37 |
| 1 |   3 | 4/19/15            | null    | 4/19/15 | M      |  35 |
| 2 |   4 | 2/21/15            | 3/15/15 | 2/21/15 | M      |  21 |
| 3 |   5 | 3/28/15            | null    | 3/28/15 | M      |  18 |
+---+-----+--------------------+---------+---------+--------+-----+
```

What are the best pandas idioms/functions to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it's the most optimal solution, but should work:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]:
   uid                 msg    _time gender  age
0    1  confirmed_settings  1/29/15      M   37
1    1                sale  4/13/15      M   37
2    3  confirmed_settings  4/19/15      M   35
3    4  confirmed_settings  2/21/15      M   21
4    5  confirmed_settings  3/28/15      M   18
5    4                sale  3/15/15      M   21

In [2]: df1 = df.pivot(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time').reset_index()
In [3]: df1 = df1.merge(df[['uid', 'gender', 'age']].drop_duplicates(), on='uid')

In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   uid confirmed_settings     sale gender  age
0    1            1/29/15  4/13/15      M   37
2    3            4/19/15      NaN      M   35
3    4            2/21/15  3/15/15      M   21
5    5            3/28/15      NaN      M   18
```

Comment: Im actually getting this error on `df1 = df.pivot(index='uid', columns='msg', values='_time').reset_index()` - `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

Comment: my version is `0.15.2`

Comment: Ok - so I upgraded to 16.0 and it didn't solve the problem, but I think I found my issue.  My data set is much larger than my example, and there must be some data error where a user has two sales or two confirm_settings.  I'm going to try and cleanse the data better and your solution should work.

Comment: Worked for me on `0.16.0`. I think pandas `0.15.2` is checking the integrity of the index for duplicates, which got probably changed in `0.16.0`